# New-PSSession - Connecting to remote server failed

Tags: powershell, windows-7-x64, powershell-4.0

I have two Windows 7 Pro systems, one host system and one in a VM one the host system. I am trying to create a New PSSession on the host system to control the guest, both of which run Powershell 4.0.

As we have a DHCP setup in the office the first thing I do is establish the IP adress of each. Then I run the code below on both machines -

```
Set-Item wsman:\localhost\client\trustedhosts "$relevantIP" -Force
```

I then test that the systems are ready using WSMan on the host -

```
Test-WSMan $remoteIP

wsmid           : http://schemas.dmtf.org/wbem/wsman/identity/1/wsmanidentity.xsd
ProtocolVersion : http://schemas.dmtf.org/wbem/wsman/1/wsman.xsd
ProductVendor   : Microsoft Corporation
ProductVersion  : OS: 0.0.0 SP: 0.0 Stack: 3.0
```

All this works perfectly well. At this point I used to create a new PSSession using the following

```
$credObject = 
            $Host.ui.PromptForCredential(
                "Need credentials", 
                "Please enter password for the following IP $remoteIP", 
                $remoteUsername, 
                ""
            )

$remoteSession = New-PSSession -ComputerName $remoteIP -Credential $credObject
```

> New-PSSession : [10.141.114.91] Connecting to remote server
>   10.141.114.91 failed with the following error message : The WinRM client cannot process the request. Default  authentication may be used
>   with an IP address under the following conditions: the transport is
>   HTTPS or the destination is in the TrustedHosts list, and explicit
>   credentials are  provided. Use winrm.cmd to configure TrustedHosts.
>   Note that computers in the TrustedHosts list might not be
>   authenticated. For more information on how to set TrustedHosts run 
>   the following command: winrm help config. For more information, see
>   the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic. At line:1 char:18
>   + $remoteSession = New-PSSession -ComputerName "10.141.114.91" -Credential "SESA40 ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (System.Manageme....RemoteRunspace:RemoteRunspace) [New-PSSession],
>   PSRemotingTransportException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotUseIPAddress,PSSessionOpenFailed

I have no idea why it has started doing this when trying to connect to the VM from the host system. I can create a new PSSession on the host machine from within the guest but no longer the other way around.

The error message says that "Default 
authentication may be used with an IP address under the following conditions: ... the destination is in the TrustedHosts list and explicit credentials are provided." I have already added the correspoding IP to each WSMan TrustedHosts fields and provide explicit credentials.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I am scratching my head trying to think of what could be wrong.

**Update**

After following the suggestion of one commentor I tried using different authentification methods.

```
$remoteSession = New-PSSession -ComputerName "10.141.114.91" -Credential "Test" -ErrorAction Stop -Authentication Basic

The WinRM client cannot process the request. Unencrypted traffic is currently 
disabled in the client configuration. Change the client configuration and try the request again.
```

So I ran `set-item WSMan:\localhost\Client\allowunencrypted $true` on both machines. Now trying to get a PSSession gives the error

```
Get-PSSession -ComputerName "10.141.114.91" -Credential "Test" -Authentication Basic

The WinRM client cannot process the request. If the authentication scheme is 
different from Kerberos, or if the client computer is not joined to a domain, then HTTPS transport must be used or the destination machine must be added to the TrustedHosts configuration setting.
```

** Update 2 **

In case anyone has the same problem and comes across this - my problem turned out to be a combination of a network fault and then with my playing around somehow creating a list of IP addresses for wsman:\localhost\client\trustedhosts which missed a comma between IP's.

Comment: Try to change the Authentication with the `-Authentication` Parameter for Basic/Default etc.

Comment: Interestingly changing the Authentification to Basic didn't fix it but did give a new error message -  

"The WinRM client cannot process the request. Unencrypted traffic is currently disabled in the client configuration. Change the client configuration and try the request again."

I ran `set-item WSMan:\localhost\Client\allowunencrypted $true` but get a very similar message...

Comment: ... "The WinRM client cannot process the request. If the 
authentication scheme is different from Kerberos, or if the client computer is not joined to a domain, then HTTPS transport must be used or the destination machine must be added 
to the TrustedHosts configuration setting."

Comment: @Flash_Steel Is this a workgroup or domain environment that you are attempting connection to?

Comment: It's on a workgroup environment. As such both systems have had wsman\TrustedHosts updated to include the other systems' IP address

Comment: So I thought this was related to Powershell. After further investigation I have discovered that the network linking the two systems, which is a physical network, has caused a couple of issues. When the problem was happening the VM could ping the host system but the host couldn't ping the VM system. This has stopped and all of a sudden I can create PSSessions on the VM from the host again. As such I have flagged this as off-topic.